# Extracting Residual Variance from Observed Indicators in CFA (Lavaan)

Tags: r, r-lavaan

When running a CFA, we build a matrix which represents the shared variance among our observed variables. This matrix can be used to represent a broader factor derived from lower-ordered variables. Further, this matrix can be extracted and analyzed with other variables in our main data frame. My question is : How do you extract the unique variance from indicators. I understand that in the summary output, it gives me mean variances of my observed indicators, but I am unable to extract these like I do the my factor scores. Here is my code :

```
library(lavaan)
library(dplyr)

data(HolzingerSwineford1939) 
head(HolzingerSwineford1939)
```

## Build and Fit Measurment Mod

```
# Build
Mes.Mod = ' 
  visual =~ x1 + x2 + x3
  textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6'

#Fit
mod_cfa = cfa(Mes.Mod, data = HolzingerSwineford1939)

#Assess
summary(mod_cfa, fit.measures = TRUE)
```

## Extract Factor Scores into Main set

```
idx = lavInspect(mod_cfa, "case.idx")
fscores = lavPredict(mod_cfa)
for(fs in colnames(fscores)) {
HolzingerSwineford1939[idx, fs] <- fscores[,fs]
}
```

### Extract Unique Variance of Observed Indicators ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Lavaan, but if you want to get the variance of a linear combination of specific covariate values, you should be able to use the covariance matrix: t(a) %*% vcov(mod_cfa) %*% a, where a is a vector of the covariate values. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/446676/measuring-standard-error-of-two-or-more-coefficients-combined

Answer (score 0):

The Question has been successfully answered here :

https://groups.google.com/u/1/g/lavaan/c/zT90_tmeJ5M

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).